# I have hidden a table in Power BI via "isHidden" but it is still visible to report developers

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've deployed a dataset to Power BI.  It includes one table that is meant to be hidden.  The TMSL for my table clearly sets the "**isHidden**" property to True.  However when report developers are connecting to this dataset in the desktop, they are able to see that table, as they design their report visuals.

Here is the explanation of the TMSL property:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/tables-object-tmsl?view=asallproducts-allversions

[image]

I'm not sure why the Power BI report developers are presented with a table that is hidden.  They see the table when building reports that connect to this dataset.

Inerestingly, we noticed that Excel users are **not presented with the hidden tables** when they connect to the dataset.

A workaround that we discovered is to create "**perspectives**" in the dataset, then connect to the dataset using a particular perspective, by way of a "**composite model**".  This workaround seems like a lot of hoop-jumping, simply for the sake of obscuring tables that aren't meant to be seen.

There appear to be some other customers who have encountered this problem, and reported to the community site ("fabric"). But their posts are a couple years old and nobody has replied.  I am also pursuing a CSS case, but those can take a very long time to resolve and I am eager to find a path forward.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Still waiting on a support case with CSS. But based on some additional testing, it appears  that you have to mark the flag (isHidden) on all columns and hierarchies, in order for the PBI "client tool" to respect the fact that you want to hide the table.

This doesn't apply to excel for some reason.  Excel will hide the table as long as the "isHidden" is set on the table as a whole.

Comment: The PG has been contacted via ICM, and they have tentatively said it may be a bug.  More to follow.